# Можно ли пропустить несуществующее поле документа при поиске?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Вот модель

```
const schema = new Schema({
    // ....
    conditions: {},
    // ....
});
```

Conditions - вложенный документ и в нём можно сохранить что угодно с любым ключом (ну, немного иначе. Здесь будут поля из другой модели, но некоторые могут отсутсовать). И допустим у нас в conditions:

```
{
    "conditions": {
        "age": 10,
        "name": "John"
    }
}
```

Это находится на базе. Теперь, я хочу найти этот документ, но т.к. я не знаю, какие там поля, сталкиваюсь с проблемом...

```
const conditions = {
    'conditions.age': 10,
    'conditions.name': 'John',
    'conditions.surname': 'White' // surname там нет
}
const result = await Model.find(conditions);
console.log(result) // [];
```

И вот вопрос, можно ли исключить из фильтра поля, которые отсутствуют в документе ? Чтобы find их просто пропускал, не учитывал... Заранее спасибо. )

Comment: что-то типа такого `$or: [{ 'conditions.surname': null }, { 'conditions.surname': 'White' }]`

Comment: @nörbörnën, Пробовал примерно так же с `$exists: false` для всех полей - не получилось...

Comment: я имел ввиду что-то типа второго запроса в ответе https://stackoverflow.com/a/47304947/4496422

Comment: сейчас попробую... Спасибо)

Comment: @nörbörnën получилось, спасибо )

Comment: написал в другой теме, щас и сюда добавлю

Answer (score 2):

Решение

```
const validConditions = {
    $and: [
      {
        $or: [
          { 'conditions.age': { $exists: false } },
          { 'conditions.age': 20 },
        ],
      },
      {
        $or: [
          { 'conditions.name': { $exists: false } },
          { 'conditions.name': 'John' },
        ],
      },
      {
        $or: [
          { 'conditions.surname': { $exists: false } },
          { 'conditions.surname': 'White' },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };

  const result = await Test.find(validConditions);
```

Хватило просто составлять запрос для SQL...

```
SELECT * FROM entries WHERE age = 20 OR age IS NULL AND name = 'John' OR name IS NULL AND surname = 'White' OR surname IS NULL
```